# Write to OSX System Drive from Windows 7 Bootcamp

Tags: macos, boot-camp

I've installed Bootcamp & Windows 7 on my MacBook Pro. While this gives me read access to the OSX System drive, any time I attempt to make change it states I need permission. Then I of course grant permission, but access is still denied. How can I write to the OSX System Drive from Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with [Paragon HFS+](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/). Works well enough but sometimes it just stops working and at least once totally corrupted the mac drive requiring a complete reinstall. I've later learned that the problem is that Microsoft does not license the NTFS specs so NTFS support is entirely reverse engineered == always going to be buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not provide drivers for Windows to write to HFS+. Apple's driver only provides read access the drive.

However, there are commercial products such as [MacDrive](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive) which provide such functionality to write to HFS+ volumes. It costs $49.99.